# How do I convert a string to a date format? C#

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, .net-4.8

I have a date formatted like this from our database `"20230125"`. How do I turn this string to a date format such as this one `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

I can probably use `insert(4, "/")` to add spaces and then turn it into a date. Anyone know of an easier way of implementing something like that?

Comment: just read the suggestions from the ask-question wizard. Usually you get some pretty decent similar posts for your problem. If those are not appropriate to solve your use-case, please add what you've tried and where the provided solutions fail your needs.

Comment: Be aware that dates don't have a format. A date is just - well a date - it doesn't care for the **representation**. In other words `"20230125"` and `"2023-01-25"` represent the exact same date, however the *represenation* is different.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain - The OP didn't seem to make the mistake that a `DateTime` has a format. The question was all about strings that represent dates.

Answer (score 0):

[`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-7.0) method converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its `DateTime` equivalent. The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly. The method returns a value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

[`DateTime.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-tostring(system-string)) method converts the value of the current `DateTime` object to its equivalent string representation **using the specified format** and the formatting conventions of the current culture.

[A date and time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) defines the text representation of a DateTime or DateTimeOffset value that results from a formatting operation.

[The "yyyy" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#yyyySpecifier) represents the year with a minimum of four digits. [The "MM" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#MM_Specifier) represents the month as a number from 01 through 12. [The "dd" custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#ddSpecifier) represents the day of the month as a number from 01 through 31.

So you can use format `yyyyMMdd` to parse your string from DB and `dd/MM/yyyy` format to convert `DateTime` object back to string with expected format.

```
string dateString = "20230125";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateValue))
{
    string formattedDate = dateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Console.WriteLine(formattedDate); // Output: 25/01/2023
}
```